# z-index Issues with HTML and CSS Modal Box

Tags: html, css

I have had to place a z-index = -1 in .main as the modal Boxes were not appearing which they are now. The .main section with .frameMain iFrame embedded in it are not clickable and are not able to click on the links inside the iFrame.

I know the issue has to do with the z-index = 1 and if I remove it the .main section works but the modal boxes don't.

Is there any alternate way for this so both outcomes work?

Attached is my HTML, CSS and screenshots of the issues.

[image]

[image]

```css
body {
 /* General Body Properties */
  font-family: Trebuchet MS, Georgia, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  margin: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
}
 * {
 /* Key element to aligning <divs> (DO NOT REMOVE) */
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
 #wrapper {
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  top: 0 
}
 .header {
 /* Header properties featuring myEd and school emblems */
  padding: 30px;
  text-align: center;
 /* Aligns links in the navBar */
  background-image: url(/Default/Img/backgroundHeader-4K.jpg);
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
 .myEd-reverse {
  width: 240px;
  height: 70px;
  float: left;
  margin-left: -60px;
  margin-top: -40px;
}
 .navBar {
 /* Sticky navBar, either relative or fixed, depending on the scroll position of the site */
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #333;
  position: sticky;
  position: -webkit-sticky;
  top: 0;
}
 .navBar a {
 /* Style the navBar links */
  float: left;
  display: block;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 6px 12px;
  text-decoration: none;
}
 .navBar a.right {
 /* Float Quick Links, Help and Log-out navBar directory items to the right of the navBar */
  float: right;
}
 .navBar a:hover {
 /* Change color on hover */
  background-color: #ddd;
  color: #000;
}
 .navBar a.active {
 /* Active Link */
  background-color: #666;
  color: #fff;
}
 .modalDialog {
 /* Modal Properties for all modals in myEd */
  position: fixed;
  font-family: Trebuchet MS, Georgia, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  background: rgba(0,0,0,0.8);
  z-index: 99999;
  opacity:0;
  -webkit-transition: opacity 400ms ease-in;
  -moz-transition: opacity 400ms ease-in;
  transition: opacity 400ms ease-in;
  pointer-events: none;
}
 .modalDialog:target {
 /* Modal Properties for all modals in myEd */
  opacity:1;
  pointer-events: auto;
}
 .modalDialog > div {
 /* Modal Properties for all modals in myEd */
  width: 400px;
  position: relative;
  margin: 10% auto;
  padding: 5px 20px 13px 20px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  background: #fff;
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(#fff, #999);
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(#fff, #999);
  background: -o-linear-gradient(#fff, #999);
}
 .close {
 /* Modal Properties for all modals in myEd */
  background: #606061;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  line-height: 10px;
  position: absolute;
  right: -5px;
  text-align: center;
  top: -10px;
  width: -5px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-weight: bold;
  -webkit-border-radius: 12px;
  -moz-border-radius: 12px;
  border-radius: 12px;
  -moz-box-shadow: 1px 1px 3px #000;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 1px 1px 3px #000;
  box-shadow: 1px 1px 3px #000;
}
 .close:hover {
  background: #00d9ff;
}
/* Modal Properties for all modals in myEd */
 .row {
 /* Alignment between sideBar and main */
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -ms-flex-wrap: wrap;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}
 .sideBar {
 /* sideBar alignment properties */
  -ms-flex: 20%;
  flex: 20%;
  background-color: #a7a7a7;
  padding: 0px;
  height: 5000px;
 /* As standard to work on all screen resolutions, overflow hides excess */
  overflow-y: scroll;
 /* Allows myEd news to scroll */
  overflow: hidden;
}
 #newsmyEd {
  width: 100%;
  height: 11.4%;
  min-height: 11.4%;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
}
 .main {
 /* Main Column */
  -ms-flex: 80%;
  flex: 80%;
  background-color: #a7a7a7;
  padding: 0px;
  height: 5000px;
 /* As standard to work on all screen resolutions, overflow hides excess */
  overflow-y: scroll;
 /* Allows embedded iFrame to scroll */
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  z-index: -1;
}
 .frameMain {
 /* Frame Properties */
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  border: 0;
  min-height: 11.4%;
}
 .footer {
 /* Footer properties */
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  background-color: #333;
}
 .footer a {
 /* Footer navBar properties */
  float: right;
  display: block;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 6px 12px;
  text-decoration: none;
}
 .footer a:hover {
 /* Change color on hover */
  background-color: #ddd;
  color: #000;
}
 .footer a.active {
 /* Active Link */
  background-color: #666;
  color: #fff;
}
 @media screen and (max-width: 700px) {
 /* Responsive Layout - If screen px is less than 700px, make sideBar and main stack on top of each other */
  .row {
   flex-direction: column;
 }
}
 @media screen and (max-width: 400px) {
 /* Responsive Layout - If screen px is less than 400px, make navBar links stack vertically on top of each other */
  .navBar a {
   float: none;
   width: 100%;
 }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<!-- Copyright (c) myEd (made by students, for students.) 2018. -->
<html lang="en">
<head>
<title>Welcome | myEd</title>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/Home/Welcome/Style/style.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.4.1/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-5sAR7xN1Nv6T6+dT2mhtzEpVJvfS3NScPQTrOxhwjIuvcA67KV2R5Jz6kr4abQsz" crossorigin="anonymous">
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="/Default/Img/faviconmyEd-16x16.png">
</head>

<body>
<script> // Required scripts for certain activities on myEd, each entry will be noted for understanding
document.getElementsByClassName("main")[0];
</script>
<div id="wrapper"> <!-- Wrapper fitting website to all screen resolutions -->
<div class="header"> <!-- Header featuring 4K Background, myEd and school emblems -->
<img src="/Default/Img/myEd-reverse.png" class="myEd-reverse" alt="myEd" title="myEd Software"> <!-- myEd Software -->
</div> 
<div class="navBar"> <!-- Main sticky navBar with categories listed -->
<a href="#" class="active" title="Home Workspace"><i class="fa fa-home"></i></a> <!-- Home -->
<a href="#" title="Learning Workspace"><i class="fa fa-book"></i></a> <!-- Learning -->
<a href="#" title="Student Management Workspace"><i class="fa fa-user"></i></a> <!-- Student Management -->
<a href="#" title="Portal Workspace"><i class="fa fa-globe"></i></a> <!-- Portals -->
<a href="#" class="right" title="Log-out"><i class="fas fa-sign-out-alt"></i></a> <!-- Log-out (right to left) -->
<a href="#" class="right" title="Help"><i class="fa fa-question-circle"></i></a> <!-- Help (right to left) -->
<a href="#modalQL" class="right" title="Quick Links"><i class="fa fa-bookmark"></i></a> <!-- Quick Links (right to left) -->

<div id="modalQL" class="modalDialog">
<div>
<a href="#close" title="Close Quick Links" class="close">X</a>
<h3>Quick Links</h3>
<h6><a href="https://kempsey.cs.adventist.edu.au/" target="_blank" rel="noopener" title="Click Here to be redirected to SEQTA Learn">SEQTA Learn</a></h6>
<h6><a href="https://kempsey.cp.adventist.edu.au/" target="_blank" rel="noopener" title="Click Here to be redirected to SEQTA Engage">SEQTA Engage</a></h6>
<h6><a href="https://www.adventist.edu.au" target="_blank" rel="noopener" title="Click Here to be redirected to ASA">Adventist Schools Australia</a></h6>
<br>
<h6><em>The links above are not available via the Portal Pages of myEd as they are unable to be embedded into the software.</em></h6>
</div>
</div>

<a href="#modalPO" class="right" title="Profile Overview"><i class="fas fa-caret-down"></i></a> <!-- Profile dropDown (right to left) -->
<div id="modalPO" class="modalDialog">
<div>
<a href="#close" title="Close Profile Overview" class="close">X</a>
<h3>Modal Box</h3>
<p>This is a sample modal box that can be created using the powers of CSS3.</p>
<p>You could do a lot of things here like have a pop-up ad that shows when your website loads, or create a login/register form for users.</p>
</div>
</div>
</div>

<div class="row"> <!-- Format for alignment of the sideBar and main panels -->
<div class="main"> <!-- Main learning or collaborative workspace -->
<iframe class="frameMain" width="100%" height="11.4%" scrolling="yes" src="/Home/Welcome/iFrame/index.html"></iframe> <!-- Embedded frame -->
</div>
<div class="sideBar"> <!-- sideBar featuring Profile, myEd News and directory -->
<iframe id="newsmyEd" frameborder="0" src="/Default/News/index.html"></iframe> <!-- myEd News -->
</div>
</div>
<div class="footer"> <!-- Featuring Site Navigation and myEd News navBar links -->
<a href="#" class="active" title="myEd News"><i class="far fa-newspaper"></i></a> <!-- myEd News -->
<a href="/Home/Welcome/siteNavigation/index.html" title="Site Navigation"><i class="fa fa-location-arrow"></i></a> <!-- Site Navigation -->
</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Thanks for your help.
Tom

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this can be accomplished when `.navBar { z-index: 100000; }`

```
.main {
    /* Main Column */
    -ms-flex: 80%;
    flex: 80%;
    background-color: #a7a7a7;
    padding: 0px;
    height: 5000px;
    /* As standard to work on all screen resolutions, overflow hides excess */
    overflow-y: scroll;
    /* Allows embedded iFrame to scroll */
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.navBar {
    /* Sticky navBar, either relative or fixed, depending on the scroll position of the site */
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color: #333;
    position: sticky;
    position: -webkit-sticky;
    top: 0;
    z-index: 100000;
}
```

Comment: Just had this working. Let me try again and post the entire source.

Comment: Replacing these two css selectors fixes the modals. Let me know if this is working. Working based on the attached snippet.

Comment: It works, thanks very much! I forgot to remove z-index = -1 from .main. Thanks for your help Shawn!

Comment: Hi @user10341225 if this or any answer has solved your question please consider accepting it by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this.